# create a measure count of values and blank in a column with dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have these columns and I want to create a measure to calculate the number of types

types

ID  Type
1   A
2   A
3   B
4   C
5   D
6   A
7
8

Results :
A 3
B 1
C 1
D 1
Blank 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **Calculated Table**:

```
Results = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Table',
    'Table'[Type],
    "Count", COUNT('Table'[ID])
)
```

[image]